# Jenssegers Laravel-Mongodb return null if get by parameter

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I'm new to Laravel-Mongodb, trying to get result by parameter but it's not working

Model:

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class Customer extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'Customer';
}
```

Controller:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return Customer::all();
    }

    public function show($id) {
        return Customer::find($id);
    }
}
```

It's alright for index() but it will return empty for show($id), it will work if using:

```
return Customer::find(1);
```

I'm not sure why it's not working with parameter, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one protected variable in your model like below

```
protected $primaryKey = “customerId”
```

You can add your own primary key to this variable but if you won’t add this line in model, model will by default take _id as your primary key and _id is autogenerated mongodb’s unique id.

Thats the reason why you are not able to get record by id.

Answer (score 0):

`1` is not a valid ObjectId. Try to find a valid ID with a tool like [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) or just list your customers with your index method to find out what the IDs are.

The query should look more like this:

return Customer::find("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011");

You can read more about MongoDBs ObjectId here:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

Comment: ic...it's strange that if I doing Customer::where('_id', $id)->get(); is not working but Customer::where('_id', 1)->get(); is work, don't know why, is it the same problem?